# Tokenizing Product Models

Tags: regex, perl, lexical-analysis

Looking to match some product info, returning structured data and rewriting or looking up the value.

Example input:

```
"I have a 1999 Cat (D-6) and an Ingersoll Rand Model Z for sale"
```

From which I want to create something like

```
[ { year:1999, brand:"CATERPILLAR", model:"D6" },
{ year:null, brand:"INGERSOLL-RAND", model:"MODEL Z" } ]
```

Based on known data:

```
/\d{4}/, YEAR
...
/cat(erpill[ae]r)/, BRAND, "CATERPILLAR"
...
/d[\-\s]6/, MODEL, "D6"
```

Can this be done with Regex alone? Or do I need a Lexer?

I can figure out the regexes no problem, but confused about the re-writing part, and grouping things together

Comment: You could do a regex for those examples, but there are probably a lot of other examples with new variations. You really need a list of all manufacturers and their abbreviations to be able to get to the find the model names accurately,

Comment: Understood. I have a list of all brands and models

Comment: OK, I have parsed this type of data before. You can do it with regexps, but is needs a lot of wrapping code, normalization and error handling to do it properly.

Comment: year regex shouldn't be `\d{4}`, you should stipulate a more narrow range like `19[89][0-9]|20[01][0-6]` to more accurately match expected input.

Comment: You would also have a `/i` flag on most of your regexes.

Comment: Absolutely. I am eliding the details of the item matching expressions, and looking more for help on the grouping and value re-writing part. Thanks!

Comment: You should do this using Conditional Random Fields for a much much better accuracy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to extract car trading details.

Here you need NLP ,You can use [Stanford Core NLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml) to design your own NLP regex or you can train a dataset.

but [Stanford NER](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml) is developed model which will give you entities like Date and time , organization also location , person ,percentage and price.

other related tools: [apache openNLP](https://opennlp.apache.org/) , [aylien](http://aylien.com/)